# Python list chunking or pagination with constraints

Tags: python, pagination

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

How do I chunk/paginate this list with constraint ? lets say my page size is 3 and per page I want only numbers divisible by two.

```
chunks = [[2,4,6],[8,10,12],[14]]
```

Changes:
Since it is pagination how do we produce one page/chunk per invocation. or in other words lets say I have a function called paginate which takes

```
def paginate(my_list, row_len, page_number=1):
```

Where page_number is the page that you are requesting for, e.g: page_number=2. special case: If you want to get all the pages, then set page_number = 0

this function can be invoked like below:

```
paginate(my_list, 3, 2)   # [8,10,12]
paginate(my_list, 3, 0)   # [[2,4,6],[8,10,12],[14]]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, give a full working example of the output you require.

Answer (score 1):

Create a *generator* for the even  numbers, then *chunk* afterward:

```
# Python 2

gen = (x for x in my_list if x%2==0)
chunks = [[i for i in t if i is not None] for t in map(None, *(gen,)*3)]
print chunks
# [[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14]]
```

---

You could avoid iterating over the entire to filter out `None` by doing the check and replacement only on the last chunk, the only possible location for a `None`:

```
gen = (x for x in my_list if x%2==0)
chunks = map(None, *(gen,)*3)
if None in chunks[-1]:
    chunks[-1] = filter(None, chunks[-1])
print(chunks)
# [(2, 4, 6), (8, 10, 12), (14,)]
```

---

In Python 3, `map(None, ...)` can be replaced with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) which ensures the shortest chunk is appended with `None`s as opposed to `zip` that simply stops at the length of the shortest iterable:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

gen = (x for x in my_list if x%2==0)
chunks = [[i for i in t if i is not None] for t in zip_longest(*(gen,)*3)]
print(chunks)
# [[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets use a 3rd party library called `more-itertools`

```
import more_itertools

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

temp = [num for num in my_list if num % 2 == 0]

list(more_itertools.chunked(temp, 3))

[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14]]
```

Here is a [link for more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: You may want to add a link to the third-party library.